# How to parse floating point infinity from std::istream

Tags: c++, serialization, floating-point

I have written a superdumb serialization library for a project that I am working on.
I just got bitten by floating point infinity, which I illustrate with the sample program below. I expect the program to print `inf -> int`, but instead it prints `inf -> 0`.
How to fix it using `std::ostream` and `std::istream` interface to give correct answer for floating point infinity (and NaNs)?

```
#include <limits>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

void serialize(std::ostream& dst, float src) {
    dst << src;
}

void deserialize(float& dst, std::istream& src) {
    src >> dst;
}

int main() {
    const float original = std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity();
    std::stringstream buffer;
    serialize(buffer, original);
    float parsed;
    deserialize(parsed, buffer);
    std::cout << original << " -> " << parsed << '\n';
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a bug. Floating point parsing using `>>` should be "... parsed as if by ... [`std::strtof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof) for `float`..." And `std::strtof` can handle `"inf"` for infinity (and `"nan"` for not a number).

Comment: I agree, that is what I expect. Can you confirm the behavior on your machine? I compiled the program with g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0

Comment: [Testing on the compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/jE88aa9r3) it seems to be a problem in the GCC standard library implementation. Clang with libc++ works as expected.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Reported as [LWG2381](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2381) for the underlying `num_get` function.

Comment: Damn that is a deep bug. Then I can switch to clang and go on with my life.