why does negative std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity() trip the fail bit in a stream on Linux but not on AIX
I'm observing differing behavior when porting to IBM Open XL C++ 17.1 (clang frontend) with this test:
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <sstream>

#define FLT_INF (std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity())

int main() {
  std::stringbuf sb;
  float val = -FLT_INF;

  // write
  std::ostream ostr_(&sb);
  ostr_.setf(std::ios::scientific, std::ios::floatfield);
  ostr_.precision(17);
  ostr_ << val << "\n";

  // verify we can read from the hard-coded stream data
  float tmp = 0.f;

  std::istream istr_(&sb);
  istr_ >> tmp;
  std::cout << val << std::endl;
  std::cout << tmp << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << istr_.fail() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}

Using Linux (GCC 11.4.1) I see the following behavior (note I also see this same behavior from Visual Studio 2022):
-inf
0
true

But on the AIX using IBM Open XL C++ 17.1 I see:
-INF
-INF
false

Notice on AIX the infinity value was successfully read from the stream and the fail state was not set.
At first I thought this was a bug with the AIX compiler but the small amount of reading I've done so far I'm not sure why all the other platforms don't handle it. It seems like a legit value std::strtof can handle (which at least based on what I've read is what basic_istream::operator>> calls (via std::num_get under the covers).
I'm near the extent of my C++ understandings. Can any C++ gurus let me know what the standard calls for behavior wise? Are both compilers right?
Thank you for your help.

Offtopic: Do not use macros for constants in C++!

apparently standard library form gcc is unable to parse inf as float (and clang can): https://godbolt.org/z/96McxraWr and AIX  can do that too.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70971921/27678

This issue ultimately boils down to the fact that different compilers treat infinity differently in their implementation of io streams.
See LWG 2381 ("Inconsistency in parsing floating point numbers") for more (reported in 2014!)
If you want a workaround in the meantime, stof appears to work fine, but you're stuck reading into a string first.
